# How to calculate the accuracy between train and test data of random forest in python

Tags: python, pandas, random-forest

I have built a random forest model and I have been used it to predict my training and testing data, which is coming from two different data frames.

I want to calculate the accuracy of the model but it did not work because my training data has 76 rows while my testing data only has 52 rows.

How can I make it in python?

So far, what I have done was trying to print the accuracy by using:

```
print("Accuracy:", metrics.accuracy_score(y_pred_test, y_pred_train))
```

and it gives me the following error:

> Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [52, 76]

Answer (score 0):

The sklearn documentation of the `metrics.accuracy_score()` function states

> Accuracy classification score.
> In multilabel classification, this function computes subset accuracy: the set of labels predicted for a sample must exactly match the corresponding set of labels in y_true.

So this function is supposed to be used strictly when shape of `y_true` == `y_pred`.

**Instead**, you can use the `model.score()` method. You will have to use the function twice, once for your test and once for your train set. Eg:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
rf_classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=200)
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(f'Final Training Accuracy: {rf.score(X_train,y_train)*100}%')
print(f'Model Accuracy: {rf.score(X_test,y_test)*100}%')
```